# what is the differance between values like null,zero and empty in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

what is the main difference between values like null,zero and empty in MySQL. Like if we set null data for a field and try to set in empty mysql does not allow to save.

One other example if set a field type date and try to leave it empty it is not allowed but when we set null it is allowed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066249/what-are-the-differences-between-null-zero-and-blank-in-sql for the same question and some answers

Answer (score 2):

**Zero** : is a value (number)

**NULL** : actually two types, First one used for Unknown Value (Exist but not known) and second one used for Not-Existence value (Not exist). Actually used for No-Value Set

**Empty** : No Display (If you want to print), you can call Blank