# How to use IS NULL in query from php

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am trying to run query from php. Part of the `WHERE` clause include the `IS NULL`.
In this case I am getting no records.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM IS NULL"
```

no records returned. When tested directly in PL/SQL I got records.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM ='cars'"
```

it's working fine records retreived.

Does PHP reject when using `IS NULL` in a query?

Comment: The error must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it actually NULL or is it just empty?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM =''
```

This query will check if your row field is **empty**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM IS NULL
```

will check if the row field is **null**

This answer provides a really good insight of their difference:

[Check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066249/what-are-the-differences-between-null-zero-and-blank-in-sql)

Comment: IN PL/SQL SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM ='' does not give records while SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM IS NULL gives records.

Comment: after '=' there should be 2 single quotes not 1 double quote. Also IS NULL is  working only if the value in the field is null. If it is empty you need to use the 2 single quotes

Comment: I'm confused... Oracle handles empty strings in a [non-standard way](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a788783879a41f5e818c62b1fa30d9fb) so `ITEM =''` will never match anything and `ITEM IS NULL` will match both cases. Additionally, it isn't clear who using PHP as client can change this semantics.

Comment: As @ÁlvaroGonzález says, this answer is not correct for Oracle databases as [`''` and `NULL` are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203493/1509264). Filtering on `WHERE ITEM = ''` is the same as `WHERE ITEM = NULL` and will never match any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do a work around and added AND 1=1 and worked.

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM IS NULL AND 1=1

Comment: I insist: there must be something else going on. Question is tagged as *php* so you surely have code that's more complex than that.